# Pause until logged in user is idle to run shell script in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, osx-lion, python-idle

I wrote a script that checks available memory (using vmstat and awk) then purges memory if less than 25% is free. Then after the purge, my Mac says (yes the goofy robot voice) the integer of available memory out loud. I find it to be less intrusive than a message box popup but my wife HATES it because she works from home some days and it freaks her out.

I'm looking for a way to set a global variable (or even touch/delete a temporary file) when keystrokes or mouse movement is detected. That way, the robot voice will be quiet when the machine is idle. I've been looking for about 3 hours with no luck. I was on the right track with this snippet:

---

```
set idleTime to (do shell script "ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | perl -ane 'if (/Idle/) {$idle=(pop @F)/1000000000; print $idle,\"\";last}'") 
set initIdleTime to idleTime repeat while idleTime ≥ initIdleTime   
set idleTime to (do shell script "ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | perl -ane 'if (/Idle/) {$idle=(pop @F)/1000000000; print $idle,\"\";last}'") 
end repeat
```

---

It "freezes" the prompt then prints out a number when the mouse is moved or a key is pressed but I don't know perl so I couldn't modify it. I'd prefer to stick with bash if possible.

Btw here are the scripts in case anyone wants to use them. Some I modified the first one, copied the second one and wrote the third one. I have the third one set in the cron to run every 10 minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash

# -- guns
# 
# Purge inactive memory with rapid i/o
# 
# 26 November 2007
# 'killall $command' is still printing to the terminal

# declare variables before= after= memPurged= pageSize= pagesPurged= AvailMem= timeout=5 # in seconds command="du /" 

showUsage="Usage: $(basename $0) [-h] [-t seconds] [-c "command"]"

function printError()  { echo >&2 $showUsage echo >&2  echo >&2 "See '$(basename $0) -h' for more details." }

function printHelp()  { echo "Purge inactive memory with rapid i/o." echo  echo $showUsage echo  echo "Supported Options" echo "-----------------" echo "-t{seconds}tSet the amount of time for the command to run. Default" echo "ttis 5 seconds." echo "-c{"command"}tSet the command to run. Default is 'du /'" echo "-httDisplay this help and exit" }

function getMemFree() {
# the "$3-0" bit is a dirty way to chop the period at the end vm_stat | awk '/Pages free/ {intMemFree=$3-0; print intMemFree}' }

function getPageSize() { vm_stat | awk '/page size/ {print $8}' }

# 
# Main
# 

while getopts ":ht:c:" option; do case $option in h ) printHelp; exit;; t ) timeout=$OPTARG;; c ) command=$OPTARG;; ?) echo >&2 "Invalid option!n"; printError; exit 3 esac done shift $(($OPTIND-1))

before=$(getMemFree)

purge

# set variables after=$(getMemFree) let pagesPurged=$after-$before pageSize=$(getPageSize)




    # calculate and print let memPurged=($pagesPurged * $pageSize / 2**20) 
let availMem=($after * $pageSize / 2**20) printf "%d MB purged." $memPurged 
say $availMem
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import re

# Get process info
ps = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-caxm', '-orss,comm'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
vm = subprocess.Popen(['vm_stat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

# Iterate processes
processLines = ps.split('\n')
sep = re.compile('[\s]+')
rssTotal = 0 # kB
for row in range(1,len(processLines)):
    rowText = processLines[row].strip()
    rowElements = sep.split(rowText)
    try:
        rss = float(rowElements[0]) * 1024
    except:
        rss = 0 # ignore...
    rssTotal += rss

# Process vm_stat
vmLines = vm.split('\n')
sep = re.compile(':[\s]+')
vmStats = {}
for row in range(1,len(vmLines)-2):
    rowText = vmLines[row].strip()
    rowElements = sep.split(rowText)
    vmStats[(rowElements[0])] = int(rowElements[1].strip('\.')) * 4096

print '%d' % ( vmStats["Pages free"]/1024/1024 )
```

and finally

```
#!/bin/bash

mf=$(perl ~/scripts/py/memfree.py)

if [ "$mf" -lt 2000 ]
then
sh2 ~/scripts/memclean.sh
else
exit
fi
```

Comment: I don't see what `purge` is doing, is it defined there and I'm just missing it? Also `mf=$(perl ~/scripts/py/memfree.py)` ??? perl for python? Finally, this is a relatively complex question. Can you pare it down to a smaller test case that shows the problem? Good luck.

Comment: The purge command is installed via the Install XCode ap. It free. Hey sorry.. that perl/python thing is a mixup. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

WINRAR!

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040330161158532

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $((`ioreg -c IOHIDSystem | sed -e '/HIDIdleTime/ !{ d' -e 't' -e '}' -e 's/.* = //g' -e 'q'` / 1000000000))
```

I hope this helps someone else. Thanks guys.

Ben Mar